# ASP.NET send url with parameters by post request (for facebook notification and click on it)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, url, post, notifications

I created a facebook app. A small game in asp.net mvc. It is a real time turn based game and i want the first player to choose his opponent, send him a facebook notification and go to the page of tthe game. The second player then clicks on this notification and also go the the page of the game. My problem is about the href parameter of the post data. In asp.net i create a webhttprequest object. But my data i have to post is like that :

But when second player click on notification the last two parameters are lost. I think it is because symbol & is used with facebook graph address and with my address. How can i write the correct postdata with all the parameters ??

Here is my code :

```
public string sendnotificationtoplay(string monid, string prenomMoi, string codetokenjeu){
try
{
    // variables to store parameter values
    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + monid + "/notifications";
    string autrePrenom = "@[" + monid + "]";
    string texte = "@[" + monid + "] ! " + prenomMoi + " wants to play with you ! \n Click here !";

    // creates the post data for the POST request
    string postData = ("access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN&template=" + texte + "&href=mywebsite.org/Index?ordredemandejeugame=2&codejeuadeux=ds&prenom1=dfdf&prenom2=fdgdfg");

    // create the POST request
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    // POST the data
    using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        requestWriter2.Write(postData);
    }

    //  This actually does the request and gets the response back
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    string responseData = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return responseData;`
```

Comment: Sidenote, `sendnotificationtoplay` is not a good name for a method. It just reads like a bunch of letters. C# has a [standard naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) for a reason. It should be `SendNotificationToPlay`.

Comment: ??? This is not my problem, and this is not I asked in my question. If you do not have any ideas to help me, don't advice me about my ability the code. It's not about that. Bye !

Comment: That's why I said it's a sidenote. And it actually is your problem. If you are going to share code with other developers and ask them to help you, then it's good to have your code conform to established standards. It promotes readability and increases the chance that someone will be able/willing to assist you. I understand that my comment doesn't directly answer the question asked, but it certainly doesn't detract from it.